# Change eclipse's built in tomcat context.xml file using WTP?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Is it possible somehow to modify the contents of the context.xml that eclipse uses when you are doing "Run as" -> "On server"... and "Debug as" -> "on server"

We have some settings that are in our production environments context.xml file and we need them to be available to eclipse built in tomcat as well.

I know we could use eclipse to run run on an external server, but thats not as convenient.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have a look at the automatically created project "Servers". There should be a folder for each configured Server. There, open the context.xml and add anything you like to be in the "default" context (Parameter-Tags for example).

Anything that's inside there will be used to populate the context.xml WTP automatically creates on publishing for each project on that Server.

Or use the **project specific way**: put a context.xml with your contents inside META-INF in your project (have a look here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_specify_the_Tomcat_context_configuration_for_my_Web_Application.3F)

Comment: Me neither! But recently I had to dig a little deeper because I had a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6678513/829941) - unfortunately this solution does not help me. But I'm glad it helped you, so the work was not in vain.

Comment: Nice! Had a similar problem. Kept having to add a value to it in development. I was doing his in notepad++, but by using the Servers project, it persisted between server startups.

Comment: I read the link in the WTP FAQ, but I'm a little confused as to "where" to put the META-INF/context.xml file within my project.  I have a Maven project in which I have a /etc/resources/context/META-INF/context.xml that is properly copied over into my WAR properly when I package.  However, how do I point tomcat to use that context.xml file from within WTP?  Or what is the correct path that WTP expects?

Comment: Just make it clearer: Search for the 'Servers' folder under your project directory.

Comment: You can also add your configuration in file Servers/Tomcat x/server.xml, inside the "Context" entry which is created when you "add the project".


If the "Eclipse WTP Tomcat server" is configured with "Publish Module Contexts to separate XML files", the content you have added in  Servers/Tomcat x/server.xml will be deployed in its own ${catalina_base}/conf/Catalina/localhost/specific_project_context.xml