# Eclipse deletes files/folders from deploy path during build

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment, build

I have two maven projects in eclipse `webapp` and `serviceImpl`. `webapp` references `serviceImpl`.

When `serviceImpl` project is closed in eclipse and I build and run the `webapp` on Tomcat, the application works fine. But when I run `webapp` while `serviceImpl` is open, I get the error, that `HTTP Status 500 - Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/serviceimpl-context.xml]`. If I look into the `META-INF` folder on the machine I see that eclipse has deleted the xml file.

When I build and run the application on the command line or in IntelliJ,  the problem does not appear either.

In eclipse the `Deployment Assembly` settings of `webapp` contains the open `serviceImpl` project and `source`references to some `serviceImpl-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Also `Java Build Path` --> `Libraries` --> `Maven Dependencies` has the `serviceImpl` node:

[image]

We are also using Spring Application Context.

EDIT:

When I do on the commandline:

`mvn clean install -P build-modules-test -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

then the xml file is created and the application works fine. But in eclipse "right-click project --> Maven --> Update project" deletes these files, but does not create them again...so the error occurs

Comment: Is this releated to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12253060/6309 ? Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6759801/6309 and http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_specify_the_Tomcat_context_configuration_for_my_Web_Application.3F

Comment: I have added some more information to the question..

Comment: An update project is not the same as an mvn install: the files are created during the package stage, stage which is not called during an Eclipse update.

Comment: So what would be the equivalent of "mvn install" in eclipse? Is it "Run as --> Maven install"?

Comment: Like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19794346/6309 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36079518/6309)

Comment: Do you know how I can pass arguments to "Maven install" such as the "-P build-modules-test -Dmaven.test.skip=true"?

Comment: You can see more at https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html. I will post an answer later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, an "update project" is not the same as an `mvn install`: the files are created during the package stage, stage which is not called during an Eclipse update.

See "[Developing with Eclipse and Maven / Running Maven Builds](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html)"

You can [define a Launch Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36079518/6309) setting with all the parameters you need:

[image: https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/figs/web/running_run-config.png]

Then you are sure to execute the same stages as the one done in command line through `mvn install`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have set the run configuration as follows: "Base directory" shows to the path where I normally run "mvn clean install" on the command line. "Goals " is set to "clean install" and "Profiles" is set to "build-modules-test" and I also have checked "Skip Tests" checkbox. So now I should be doing exactly the same as "mvn clean install -P build-modules-test -Dmaven.test.skip=true". But I am getting an error when I run this in eclipse. It says many times "package .... does not exist". I have checked the specific generated jar in my local maven repository and unarchived it.

Comment: When using command line, the jar contains a lot of class files etc... but when I do the "Maven install" (with my configuration described in the comment earlier" the jar does not contain these classes....any idea??